# TOP (100) PERCENT when designing a view

Tags: sql-server

When designing a view (adding Order By clause) the wizard in SSMS automatically adds

> TOP (100) PERCENT

What do we need it for? Are there any performance consideratons regarding  TOP (100) PERCENT?

Thank you

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/why-does-order-by-not-belong-in-a-view/

Comment: @AaronBertrand the middle two links are broken. Here are web archive links: [Why people think SQL 2000 behaviors live on](https://sqlblog.org/2012/02/28/why-people-think-some-sql-server-2000-behaviors-live-on-12-years-later), [Bad habits: relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ORDER BY is not allowed on VIEWS unless you set a TOP() clause.

The wizard adds it automatically just to avoid the error.

Have a look at [CREATE VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) on MS Docs.

> **The SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the following:**
>
> - An ORDER BY clause, unless there is also a TOP clause in the select list of the SELECT statement
>
> ```
>     Important:  
>     The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the 
>     TOP or OFFSET clause in the view definition. The ORDER BY clause does not 
>     guarantee ordered results when the view is queried, unless ORDER BY is also 
>     specified in the query itself.
> ```
>
> - The INTO keyword
> - The OPTION clause
> - A reference to a temporary table or a table variable.

You should add ORDER BY clause in your query:

```
SELECT   F1, F2, F3, F4
FROM     YOUR_VIEW
ORDER BY F1, F2
```

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.